# Query Performance Check

Tags: sql, database, oracle, query-optimization, query-performance

My SQL script has 10 queries in a `BEGIN END` block. I need to check performance of each query separately for single Run.

Example:
when i run the SQL script
there are 10 queries 
so need performance data for each query once it is executed 
like

```
BEGIN
query1 
performance data for query one
query2
performance data for query one
END
```

Comment: `set timing on` is probably what you're after, assuming this is a SQL*Plus script.

Comment: Simple way is to enable SQL trace. 
 See: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/TGSQL/tgsql_trace.htm#TGSQL812. 
 Better way is to use DBMS_HPROF, but it's more difficult. 
 See: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_hprof.htm#BABFDCAA

Comment: Alternatively, create a log table and log the start/end times of each query.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL*Plus you can SET TIMING ON to get the elapsed time of each query. It's a simple as this:

```
set timing on

select * from t23
/

select * from t42
/

select * from t69
/

set timing off
```

But wall-clock timings are a pretty crude measure of performance. Oracle has more to offer.

If you have a friendly DBA (and aren't they all?) get them to grant you the PLUSTRACE role. With this role you can just SET AUTOTRACE ON STATISTICS and get useful information regarding resource consumption for each query. Also you can set it with EXPLAIN to get a Explain Plan after each query too.

[Find out more](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e16604/ch_eight.htm)